# How does the "Certificate Approver Email" fit on the ssl-certificate workflow?

Tags: email, ssl-certificate

How does the "Certificate Approver Email", required upon certificate generation, fit in the certification process as a whole ?

More specifically:

- Is it important only for certificate generation ?
- Should it be available after the certificate generation complete ?
- When / why should emails be sent to this address ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that an approval of some sort (typically email) is needed is to ensure that the owner of the domain either requested the certificate, or approves the issuance of the certificate if they didn't request it.

To address your questions specifically:

> Is it important only for certificate generation ?

Generally, yes, but the use of it depends completely on the vendor of the certificate.

> Should it be available after the certificate generation complete ?

You mean, should that email account still be accessible?  Ehh, probably not necessary, but you might want it.

> When / why should emails be sent to this address ?

Well, the approval process for a specific SSL certificate should only require a one-time email, but again, all of the implementation details can vary between certificate authorities.